# How to get the background image url of anchor tag using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to give hover effect to multiple images on single page.

There is separate hover image for each image so I am using dynamic background image change.

My logic is :

1. use 2 anchor tag and hide 1 one them
2. hidden image contains the image which should shown on hover image.
3. When user hovers, first anchor tag's background image should be get replaced with hidden anchor tag's bg-image.

here is my code :

```
    <td class="cell-style-img">
    <a href="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>" id="img<?php echo '-'.$founder_count;?>" class="img-circular img_hover" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $src;?>);"/>
    <a href="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>" class="img-circular" style="display:none;background-image: url(<?php echo $hover_src;?>);" id="hover<?php echo '-'.$founder_count;?>"/>

    </a>
    </td>
$("a.img_hover").bind({

    mouseenter: function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var id1 = id.replace (/[^\d.]/g, ''); 
      id1 = 'hover-'+(id1);
      //alert(id1);
      var bg = $("#"+id1).css('background-image').replace(/^url|[\(\)]/g, '');

      bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    $("#"+id).css('background-image', bg );
    },
    mouseout: function () {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var id1 = id.replace (/[^\d.]/g, ''); 
      id1 = 'hover-'+(id1);
             $("#"+id).show();
             $("#"+id).show();
    }
});
```

My Problem is that I am not able to get second hidden anchor tag's bg-image.

How I can get the background-image of anchor tag using jquery.

Comment: Okay, could you show us the rendered HTML (as seen by the browser, 'view source'); PHP is irrelevant to a jQuery question about client-side interaction.

Comment: Instead of using `style="background-image:` perhaps add an `img` element and can more easily swap the `src` attribute?

Comment: You could also grab the `style` attribute and remove the `display:none;` from the string to give you the full `background-image:` and use that for the `style` attribute of the other!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making multiple elements, use the `data-*` attribute.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-hover="url('image2.jpg')" style="background-image: url('image1.jpg');">&nbsp;</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a').hover( function() {
    var hoverImg = $(this).data('hover');
    var basicImg = $(this).css('background-image');
    $(this).data('hover', basicImg ).css('background-image', hoverImg );
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/8captvzu/)

<strike>Maybe I'm looking at it to easy, but why not use CSS for it (since you already use id's on the images):</strike>

```
a#imgId {
    background-image: url('image1.jpg');
}
a#imgId:hover {
    background-image: url('image2.jpg');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruootuzd/)

Comment: It looks as though the background images are coming dynamically from the server and the OP is looking to move them around on the client.

Comment: Ah, I guess your right, and I was looking at it too easy. I got another idea... let me work it out.

Comment: I am getting image dynamically, so I cant use static css code

Comment: Jup, my bad. I've edited my answer, giving you a jQuery solution. Hope it suits you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is way too complex for such a simple problem. Try something simpler, like letting CSS do the heavy-lifting.

This obviously won't fit your scenario out-of-the-box (because I can't see exactly what it is you're doing), but it should lead down the right (or at least easier) path.

[**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u93efzb5/](http://jsfiddle.net/u93efzb5/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="reveal" style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-g-256-256-5.jpg);">
    <span style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-256-256-9.jpg);" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a.reveal {
    display: block;
    height: 256px; width: 256px;
    position: relative;
}
a.reveal span {
    display: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
}

a.reveal:hover span {
    display: block;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
```